# how to change fontcolor of asp:menu that read items from sitemap

Tags: asp.net, css, aspmenu

how can i change my fontcolor of asp:menu that it read items from sitemap?
ccsClass not worked on it!
this is my code:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1"  
StaticDisplayLevels="2" CssClass="MyMenu"  
StaticSubMenuIndent="18px"   
DynamicMenuItemStyle-BackColor="#C0C0BC"  
DynamicHoverStyle-BackColor="#B3B3B3"  
StaticHoverStyle-BackColor="#666666"  
StaticHoverStyle-ForeColor="#d9d9d6"  
StaticMenuItemStyle-VerticalPadding="1px" StaticPopOutImageUrl="~/Images/control_rewind_blue.png" >
```

this is ccsClass:

```
.MyMenu{color:White; font-family:Tahoma; font-size:medium;}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add color by forecolor and you can add style as well

```
 <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" ForeColor="#003399" style="left: 40px; position: relative; top: 6px" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1"  
        StaticDisplayLevels="2" CssClass="MyMenu"  
        StaticSubMenuIndent="18px"   
        DynamicMenuItemStyle-BackColor="#C0C0BC"  
        DynamicHoverStyle-BackColor="#B3B3B3"  
        StaticHoverStyle-BackColor="#666666"  
        StaticHoverStyle-ForeColor="#d9d9d6"  
        StaticMenuItemStyle-VerticalPadding="1px" StaticPopOutImageUrl="~/Images/control_rewind_blue.png" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a class for every operation on `asp:Menu` like this :

```
<asp:Menu ID="AspMenu" runat="server">

<StaticMenuStyle CssClass="VerticalMenuli" />
<StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="VerticalMenuItem" />
<StaticHoverStyle CssClass="VerticalMenuHover" /> 
<StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="VerticalMenuSelectedItem" />

<DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="VerticalMenuSubMenu" />     
<DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="VerticalMenuSubMenuItem" />
<DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="VerticalSubMenuHover" /> 
<DynamicSelectedStyle CssClass="SubMenuSelected"/>
```

And now you can give formatting in the defined class for any sub menu or link.